# NodeJS Pagination with distinct()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I got dta from mongoDB and I am doing a pagination with a JSON API (display the ids).

I use `require('mongoose-query-paginate');`

```
var query = Cars.find().distinct('folder');
query.paginate(options, function(err, ids) {
    res.status('ids').send({
          ids: ids
        });
});

Error: skip cannot be used with distinct
at Query._validate (C:\nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mquery\lib\mquery.js:2405:11)
        ...
```

I have a problem (conflict?) with skip() and distinct.

How I can fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` is a special purpose aggregation function that returns an array rather than a cursor and it doesn't accept skip or limit arguments. You won't be able to use paginate with it. Instead, you can construct an equivalent aggregation pipeline, which will return a cursor for MongoDB >= 2.6:

```
> db.cars.aggregate([{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$folder" } }])
```

This kind of cursor also doesn't accept skips and limits, but you can use the `$skip` and `$limit` pipeline stages to make your pages:

```
> db.cars.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$folder" } }
    { "$skip" : 691 },
    { "$limit" : 37 }
])
```

As a final note, using $skip and $limit for pagination is inefficient. The better solution is to use $sort and retrieve each page as the next N records > the largest record on the previous page. This can be done with the aggregation as well by using the $sort stage.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still have a problem: TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'paginate' . The query works fine console.log(query) but the error is coming when query.paginate(options, function(err, ids)...